# Animating the change of a hidden div width with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, width, hidden

I have been trying to get this to work for a few days.

Basically i have a div `Option1Div` and a image with the id `Option1`, When you click the image it should change the `div` from `Hidden` to `Visible`, and change the width from 0 to 500px, but so far nothing happens.

```
$('#Option1').click(function() {
  $('#Option1Div').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    width: "500 px"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

Comment: What is your CSS for `#Option1Div`? If you've hidden it by using `display: hidden;` you won't be able to show it no matter how much you animate or otherwise change opacity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close. The CSS should be something like this:

```
 #Option1Div { width: 0; height: 100px; opacity: 0; }
```

and the jQuery

```
$('#Option1').click(function() {
      var ele = $('#Option1Div');
      ele.animate({

               opacity    : 1,
               width      : '500px'

          }, 5000, function() {
          // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/haHxC/

Comment: Still can't get it to work even with Option 1's css as you recomend, this is so frustrating http://tokusatsu.lurkerlordx.com/prototype.html

Comment: It works in the console. There must be a problem somewhere else in your JS.

Comment: This might help add some clarity, prototype.html with all the JS cleared except the call to the shortcut click method — jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8MvE/

Comment: did that, commeting out all the JS except animat and...still no go http://tokusatsu.lurkerlordx.com/prototype.html

Comment: I don't see the jQuery Library in your doc— 'jquery.js'— that's most likely the issue. Also, make sure everything is wrapped in the $(document).ready(function() { //Code }); – Clayton Misura 4 mins ago edit

Comment: you don't see the "jquery-1.8.2.min.js" link?
Ah it was the lack of DocumentReady

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that. Just took a quick look.

Answer (score 3):

If your div has `display:none` you have to make it visible first since the display is independent of the opacity.
Try:

```
$('#Option1').click(function() {
    $('#Option1Div').css({'display':'block','opacity':0}).animate({
        opacity: 0.25,
        width: "500 px"
    }, 5000, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it :) it's worth noting that you could also keep the element visible but "hide" it on page load with JQ `$("#Option1Div").css( 'opacity', 0);`

Comment: @SetSailMedia sure, but you have to be careful with that, since it is still _there_ in that case, it's just transparent. Meaning it can be clicked and interacted with, which probably isn't the desired effect.

Comment: i used Visibility: none to hide it. And besides it's a little hard to click a content Div with a default width of 0

Comment: @NekoLLX You're right. in your case it's not a problem. But in others it might be.

Answer (score 1):

I can see you are using the code directly from the jQuery animate() manual. Also from that page: `Note: Unlike shorthand animation methods such as .slideDown() and .fadeIn(), the .animate() method does not make hidden elements visible as part of the effect.`

```
$('#Option1').click(function() {
  $('#Option1Div').show().animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    width: "500 px"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```